# How can I retrieve information from firebase and display it in a HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, database, firebase

can someone help me, this is my firebase database and I'd like to retrieve a list of users (just showing information at the moment) from the database
and display it in a normal html table using javascript

https://www.up-00.com/i/00124/7bfnz8c0mt5d.png

I'd like to show that users table (first name, last name...)

**UPDATE:** Here is the code I tried, without success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing a table</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBgXArM80ikVWaTWincfffsYa85I31uf0",
    authDomain: "sosservice-1b5a7.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sosservice.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sosservice-1b5a7",
    storageBucket: "sosservice-1445e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1093429197188"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
</head>
<body>


<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>CIN</th>
    <th>Tel</th>
    <th>Pass</th>

 </table> 

<script>
    var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(users).once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + val.firstName + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.lastName + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.cin + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.numTel + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.pw + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just Google the title of your question you will find several answers: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=How+can+I+retrieve+information+from+firebase+and+display+it+in+a+HTML+table+using+javascript. For example https://labs.bawi.io/creating-a-dynamic-html-table-using-real-time-update-with-firebase-c01059a6c857

Comment: I found a lot of anwsers in google but non of them is a clear code that works flawlessly

Comment: What code have you tried and what is the problem with it? We'll help you understand how to fix it. But we wont write the bloody thing from scratch.

Comment: I tried this code: https://pastebin.com/raw/dQBUYuYt
yet it didnt show anything

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not very far from the solution with the code you tried! (I modified your question to include this new code).

There are three problems:

1. Apparently your Firebase project is not correctly spelled in the HTML page. You will receive an error like `"FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://sosservice.firebaseio.com)"`.
2. By doing `database.ref(users).once('value', function(snapshot) {})` you are passing a variable users to the `ref()` method, but `users` is not defined anywhere. You need to pass the string `'users'`, as follows: `database.ref('users').once('value', function(snapshot) {})`.
3. By doing `$('#ex-table').append(content);` it means that you are using the famous jQuery library. For this to work, you need to include the jQuery JavaScript file in your page. You can either download it or point to a version hosted by a CDN, see https://jquery.com/download/

So, the following code should work, making the assumption that the Firebase config is correctly declared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing a table</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBgXArM80ikVWaTWincfffsYa85I31uf0",
          authDomain: "sosservice-1b5a7.firebaseapp.com",  //Check here!!
          databaseURL: "https://sosservice.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "sosservice-1b5a7",
          storageBucket: "sosservice-1445e.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "1093429197188"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
      <tr id="tr">
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>CIN</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
        <th>Pass</th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      var database = firebase.database();
      database.ref('users').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          var content = '';
          snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + val.firstName + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.lastName + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.cin + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.numTel + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.pw + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
          });
          $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed the code and now it works correctly :)